# Make CPT archive editable and integrate Thrive Architect

Tags: php, css, wordpress, custom-post-type

Just bumped into this issue regarding CPT Archive pages, is there a way to make it like a page/post that you can edit and add content on it?

Currently my method is to make an ordinary page and layout the page with thrive architect then save

Then on the CPT archive page, i just add in a query to pull the contents of that page I just created

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'page_id=9755' );
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
$the_query->the_post();
the_content();
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

NOW THE CONTENT SHOWS ON MY CPT ARCHIVE, the problem now is that the styling is different, I think its related to the thrive architects ID usage which is not present in the CTP archive

[image]

so meaning I got the content working but the layout is not working

the

```
<style class="tve_custom_style"></style>
```

is different on both, so how do I get the stylesheet on that page to my CPT archive page

Comment: You are currently doing it correctly. What is the markup difference? It seems like you could easily solve this with CSS or wrapping your `query` in the same markup.

Comment: well, on the normal page, I set the container width to 1000px but on the CPT archive its full width, also this type of css [data-css="tve-u-169d7a7171b"] is not visible in the CPT archive

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my own question, here is my solution

as I was doing this on my CPT archive

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'page_id=9755' );
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
$the_query->the_post();
the_content();
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

the css layout does not follow from the original page to my CPT archive

the solution is

```
<?php 
$custom_css = trim( tve_get_post_meta( 9755, 'tve_custom_css', true ) . tve_get_post_meta( 9755, 'tve_user_custom_css', true ) );
echo '<style>';
echo $custom_css;
echo '</style>';
?>
```

so that tve_get_post_meta() pulled the stylesheet from that page to my CPT archive

AND ALL IS WORKING FINE...